# d3: Brush with an input field

Tags: html, d3.js, input, brush

I'm making a d3 brush similar to the demo shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6232620). However, I'd like to have the brush contain an `<input>` element, and when the brush is moved the `<input>` should move along with it.

Is this possible, perhaps by using a foreignObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
var bbox = gBrush.node().getBBox();
gBrush.select(".resize.e").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -bbox.width)
  .attr("y", bbox.height)  
  .append("xhtml:body").append("xhtml:input").attr("size",4)
  .attr("type", "text")
  .html("Object in SVG");
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 200,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 200,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([new Date(2013, 2, 1), new Date(2013, 2, 15) - 1])
  .range([0, width]);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
  .x(x)
  .extent([new Date(2013, 2, 2), new Date(2013, 2, 3)])
  .on("brush", brushed);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "grid-background")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x grid")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.hours, 12)
    .tickSize(-height)
    .tickFormat(""))
  .selectAll(".tick")
  .classed("minor", function(d) {
    return d.getHours();
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom")
    .ticks(d3.time.days)
    .tickPadding(0))
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("x", 6)
  .style("text-anchor", null);

var gBrush = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "brush")
  .call(brush);

var bbox = gBrush.node().getBBox();
gBrush.select(".resize.e").append("foreignObject")
  .attr("x", -bbox.width)
  .attr("y", bbox.height)  
  .append("xhtml:body").append("xhtml:input").attr("size",4)
  .attr("type", "text")
  .html("Object in SVG");

gBrush.selectAll("rect")
  .attr("height", height);

function brushed() {
  var extent0 = brush.extent(),
    extent1;

  // if dragging, preserve the width of the extent
  if (d3.event.mode === "move") {
    var d0 = d3.time.day.round(extent0[0]),
      d1 = d3.time.day.offset(d0, Math.round((extent0[1] - extent0[0]) / 864e5));
    extent1 = [d0, d1];
  }

  // otherwise, if resizing, round both dates
  else {
    extent1 = extent0.map(d3.time.day.round);

    // if empty when rounded, use floor & ceil instead
    if (extent1[0] >= extent1[1]) {
      extent1[0] = d3.time.day.floor(extent0[0]);
      extent1[1] = d3.time.day.ceil(extent0[1]);
    }
  }

  d3.select(this).call(brush.extent(extent1));
}
```

```css
.axis text {
  font: 11px sans-serif;
}
.axis path {
  display: none;
}
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid-background {
  fill: #ddd;
}
.grid line,
.grid path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.grid .minor.tick line {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
.brush .extent {
  stroke: #000;
  fill-opacity: .125;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! For some reason the input won't appear unless I give the foreignobject an explicit width and height, do you know why that might be?